# mysql concat all field table

Tags: mysql, concatenation

Is there a way we can concat all field in the table(1 sql statement)(automatic) ?
The reason was before user updated or delete a record,the record will push to another table for future reference.

Answer (score 1):

Why concat then? Why not to push to another table whole row as is?

insert into anothertable select * from thisone

Comment: INSERT INTO `dummy` (`dummy_text`) VALUES((SELECT * FROM `accordian` WHERE 1 LIMIT 1))

Error :Operand should contain 1 column.
If mysql can auto concat the field + | or  ,  is  more easier to  see before and after value comparison.

Comment: in the end i make php script to compare old value and new value and diffirence output in json format.Quite long code but it worthy.